# Debugging applications in QTCreator

Tags: qt-creator, gdb

Every time I go to debug some code in QTCreator, I get this GDB error returning.

```
Current setup: Ubuntu 11.04
QT Creator version: 2.1.0
GDB Version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2

Debugging starts
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Invalid argument\n"
```

I've also tried debugging from CLI with the following results:

```
charles@virtubuntu:~/Documents/it327/Day3/Lab1-build-desktop$ qtcreator -debug Lab1
Warning: HANDLE RUNCONTROL START FAILED (no active run control)
UNEXPECTED STATE TRANSITION:  "State changed from EngineSetupFailed(2) to DebuggerFinished(21)." 
Warning: State changed from EngineSetupFailed(2) to DebuggerFinished(21). (no active run control)
Warning: (gdb)  (no active run control)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this so I can actually debug my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this was fixed in Qt Creator 2.2.0, [#2837](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTCREATORBUG-2837).

Version 2.2.1 will be available with Oneiric.

Comment: I'm holding out to see if someone has a fix for 11.04, but this was a good find. Thank you